# OpenSSL EVP AES/DES Encryption Implementation

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to implement some basic AES/DES encryption/decryption in small apps. Mainly to store sensitive user information.

I've seen a lot of examples of implementations in C which is what I want because it's easy to use in Objective-C later, but I can't really make them work. Most of the examples are from 5-10 years ago and have a lot of deprecated and unused stuff and I can't simply make them work. Other just end up in segmentation fault and other errors.

Lately I've been reading a book called "Network Security With OpenSSL". It has a lot of interesting content, but I can't compile most of the examples.

I was already able to encrypt/decrypt stuff using OpenSSL in PHP and on the command line interface too, but no luck with C.

Can someone please give me working examples from today (not from 10 years ago!) how I should work with this in C?

Comment: AES hasn't changed since 1998...

Comment: @DietrichEpp but the OpenSSL EVP seem to be changing. I can't get to work most of the examples.

Answer (score 2):

From the same folks:
https://opensource.conformal.com/viewgit/?a=viewblob&p=cyphertite&h=899259f8ba145c11087088ec83153db524031800&hb=6782c6839d847fbed0aed8c55917e78b5684110f&f=cyphertite/ct_crypto.c

Look at the ct_crypto_* functions.  They use AES-XTS which is a much better idea then DES (don't use DES!!)

Code compiles and works like a champ.  There are examples in the code but they might be a little tangly but everything is there to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

The best example I know of which is both concise and useable out-of-the-box is AgglomeratedSSL, which is an OpenSSL wrapper: https://opensource.conformal.com/wiki/Agglomerated_SSL. Comes with a few example clients and servers using the wrapper API, and the code itself is an example of using OpenSSL for basic tasks.

PS: For a humorous look at the state of OpenSSL documentation, see http://www.peereboom.us/assl/assl/html/openssl.html

Comment: Thanks, the humorous page is really what I feel right now. LOL Anyway, the assl seems to be good, but it's focused in SSL/TLS not in data encryption/decryption using cyphers...